# Winnovative HTML to PDF converter

Tags: javascript, html, pdf-generation, winnovative

I'm trying to convert an aspx page to a PDF using the Winnovative HTML to PDF converter, but before the page is converted, I want some javascript to be run. I know the javascript works as I've tested the standalone aspx page without converting it to a PDF. However, when it is converted, it appears that the javascript hasn't been run. I have read the FAQs on the Winnovative website (http://www.winnovative-software.com/FAQ.aspx) and as a result I've added the following to my code to ensure javascript can be allowed to run:

```
pdfConverter.ScriptsEnabled = True
pdfConverter.InternetSecurityZone = InternetSecurityZone.LocalMachine
```

Adding this code still didn't work so I tried commenting out my main javascript and testing a very simple bit of javascript to see if that works. The javascript I tried was simply:

```
var item = $(".items")[0];
items.style.display = "none";
```

The element with a class of "items" surrounds everything on the page. When I generated the PDF again, all the contents had disappeared as expected. This means that javascript is running.

I then wondered if maybe the PDF is being generated before my javascript has had a chance to run so that's why the effects can't be seen. I found in the Winnovative website's FAQs that the PDF converter has a ConversionDelay property which can be used to specify an additional period of time in seconds to wait for asynchronous content to be loaded before starting PDF rendering. So I added the following:

```
pdfConverter.ConversionDelay = 30
```

Even after this delay, my javascript still does not run. Can anyone please offer any guidance? Thanks.

Comment: are you running your js code inside document.ready???

Comment: @Haroon yes I am, and the script is at the bottom of the page so it runs after the content has loaded as well if that's any use

Comment: Any news on this issue? I've the same problem

Comment: @Haroon does your question mean that you have an answer or a suggestion on this problem?

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I've been hit with this too.

Answer (score 1):

I found that another product from winnovative "EVO HTML to PDF Converter for .NET" does a good javascript execution, it works also with jquery.

Here is the test page:http://www.evopdf.com/evopdfdemo/default.aspx and I tried the conversion successfully with these jQuery rendered pages:

[jQuery Accordion](http://www.webdesignerwall.com/demo/jquery/accordion1.html) (the tabs are correctly rendered)

[jQuery pagination](http://d-scribe.de/webtools/jquery-pagination/demo/demo_options.htm) (the pages numbers created by jquery are visible)

In this two examples the winnovative html to pdf conversion fails.

---

EDIT: It seems that the EVO library has problem on relative scripts include not starting with "/"

If you need to link an external script you have three options:

1. Add a script reference using the Absolute Path like

   ```
   <script src="www.myserver.com/myjsfile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   ```
2. Insert the script inside the original page using the <script> tag
3. Use a relative path with "/" like

   ```
   <script src="/myjsfile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   ```

Comment: Cheers, noticed you missed the extra four space indentation in the list. :)

Answer (score 0):

One workaround for this problem would be to save the page source *after* JavaScript has run on a browser, and then pass that HTML file to the converter.

You can install the [Web Developer Toolbar](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/) for Firefox and use the View Source -> View Generated Source feature to get the HTML of the page in its current state, and then save that to a file.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but unfortunately because the HTML that's generated is dynamic dependant on various parameters, this isn't possible.